# How to add interceptor to all API requests except one or two?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

I know it's possible to add an interceptor to all requests through an `OkHttpClient`, but I would like to know if it's possible to add headers to all requests in `Okhttp` except for one request or two using the `OkHttpClient`.

For example, in my **API** all requests require a bearer token (`Authorization: Bearer token-here` header) except for the `oauth/token` (to get a token) and `api/users` (to register a user) routes. Is it possible to add an interceptor for all requests except the excluded ones using the `OkHttpClient` in one step or should I add the headers individually for each request?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the answer!

Basically I needed an interceptor as usual and I needed to check the *URL* there to know whether I should add the authorization header or not.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

/**
 * Created by Omar on 4/17/2017.
 */

public class NetInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        if (request.url().encodedPath().equalsIgnoreCase("/oauth/token")
                || (request.url().encodedPath().equalsIgnoreCase("/api/v1/users") && request.method().equalsIgnoreCase("post"))) {
            return  chain.proceed(request);
        }
        Request newRequest = request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer token-here")
                .build();
        Response response = chain.proceed(newRequest);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

@Omar answer is Good :) but I found a more clean way to implement using custom annotation.

Add annotation

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
private annotation class DECRYPTRESPONSE
```

check if the annotation is true or false in an intercepter like this

```
val method = chain.request().tag(Invocation::class.java)!!.method()
    if(method.isAnnotationPresent(DECRYPTRESPONSE::class.java)) {
       //when annotion is present
} else..
```

add an annotation in retrofit interface

```
@DECRYPTRESPONSE
@GET
Call<ItemsModel> getListing(@Url String url);
```

below is the complete code of my interceptor also don't forget to add intercepter in the Okhttpclient builder

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
private annotation class DECRYPTRESPONSE

    class DecryptInterceptor : Interceptor {
    
        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response = chain
            .run {
                proceed(request())
            }
            .let { response ->
                return@let if (response.isSuccessful) {
    
                    val body = response.body!!
                    val contentType = body.contentType()
                    val charset = contentType?.charset() ?: Charset.defaultCharset()
                    val buffer = body.source().apply { request(Long.MAX_VALUE) }.buffer()
                    val bodyContent = buffer.clone().readString(charset)
    
                    val method = chain.request().tag(Invocation::class.java)!!.method()
    
                    if(method.isAnnotationPresent(DECRYPTRESPONSE::class.java)) {
                        response.newBuilder()
                            .body(ResponseBody.create(contentType, bodyContent.let(::decryptBody)))
                            .build()
                    }
                    else{
                        response.newBuilder()
                            .body(ResponseBody.create(contentType, bodyContent))
                            .build()
                    }
    
                } else response
            }
    
        private fun decryptBody(content: String): String {
            
              return content //your decryption code
        }
    }
```